# Displaying RoR relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationships

I have setup a model relationship and all is working well when I use code similar to:

```
@parent.child.each do |item|
item.name
end
```

But how would I call just a specific child given there id

eg.

Child ID is 14

Would like a call like:

```
@parent.child[childid].name #>>>>>> CHILD'S NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

`@parent.child[14]` would most likely not work correctly, `child` is an array, if it is a `has_many` relation, but the array index is not the same as the id of the child. so you can do something like this:

```
@parent.child.find(14).name
```

I'm not really sure, but if you do something like this:

```
@parent = Parent.find(some_id, :include => :child)
@parent.child.find(some_other_id) # should hit the query cache
```

Comment: That works, but is there any other ways to do it other then making more db calls?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@parent.children.detect { |child| child.id == 14 }
```

This should return the object without querying the database. You can then call the `.name` method on it.